# Express route to return clean json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this express route that returns me the number of carnapping crimes per month. In the variable records, to explain it further, `{"1":[{"1":2}]`, where the first 1 is query#1 and the next 1 indicates as January as the 1st month of the year. and lastly, 2 which indicates the number of crimes in the month of January.

```
app.get('/carnapping-route', function(req, res){  
    var records1 = [{"1":[{"1":2}],"2":[{"2":1}],"3":[{"3":2}],"4":[{"4":1}],"5":[{"5":1}],"6":[{"6":1}],"7":[{"7":1}],"8":[{"8":1}],"9":[{"9":1}],"10":[{"10":1}],"11":[{"11":1}],"12":[{"12":1}]}];
    var counts = [ ];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var key = i + "";
        counts.push(records[0][key][key]);
    }   
        res.send(counts);               
});
```

Instead of getting `[2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, I get `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]`

What did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

In your data structure you have an array in `records[0][key]` variable. So you need to use `records[0][key][0][key]` in `push` method

```js
var records1 = [{"1":[{"1":2}],"2":[{"2":1}],"3":[{"3":2}],"4":[{"4":1}],"5":[{"5":1}],"6":[{"6":1}],"7":[{"7":1}],"8":[{"8":1}],"9":[{"9":1}],"10":[{"10":1}],"11":[{"11":1}],"12":[{"12":1}]}];
var counts = [ ];
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    var key = i + "";
    counts.push(records1[0][key][0][key]);
}
//res.send(counts); 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=counts;
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```